# How do I use the name of any lower class as a variable in a higher class?

Tags: python, class, class-variables

When I run this Python program, `dog.bark()` returns  "This **dog** is barking" but `dog.eat()` returns "This **animal** is eating".

I need `dog.eat()` to also return "This dog is eating" using a variable similarly to this:

```
class Animal(Organism):

    def eat(self):

        print("This ***{self}*** is eating")
```

This would allow other animals to also return their own name instead of "animal". E.g "This turtle is eating, this squirrel is eating, etc.

Obviously `{self}` is not the right syntax, that's why I'm looking for answers or resources regarding what I'm trying to do. If you could reply or redirect me that would be super nice.

```
class Organism:

    alive = True

class Animal(Organism):

    def eat(self):
        print("This animal is eating")

class Dog(Animal):

    def bark(self):
        print("This dog is barking")

dog = Dog()
dog.eat()
dog.bark()
```

Comment: `f'This {type(self).__name__.lower()} is eating'`…?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `name()` function that you override in each subclass, then call that to generate the output string:

```
class Animal(Organism):

    def name(self):
        return "animal"

    def eat(self):
        print(f"This {self.name()} is eating")

class Dog(Animal):

    def name(self):
        return "dog"

    def bark(self):
        print("This dog is barking")
```

Even simpler, but less flexible, is to make the name a class attribute instead:

```
class Animal(Organism):

    NAME = "animal"

    def eat(self):
        print(f"This {self.NAME} is eating")

class Dog(Animal):

    NAME = "dog"

    def bark(self):
        print("This dog is barking")
```

Comment: No real reason to make `name` a method instead of a simple class attribute… Also sounds like OP just wants to use the already existing class name.

Comment: I would not use the class name directly. If I rename the class during refactoring, I would want the output of the program to stay the same. And what about animals like the `BaldEagle`? You wouldn't want to turn that into `baldeagle`.

Comment: That's up to OP to decide. You _could_ apply intelligent CamelCase to lower case formatting if you needed it. — As for your edit: using an attribute is also hardly "less flexible", you can replace it with a `@property` at any time if you need it to do more than just being a plain value.